# Difference between concat of strings s=s+"0" and s+="0" in c++

Tags: c++, string, string-concatenation

I want to know which one is better in terms of "time complexity" from these two:

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
s=s+"0";
}
```

and

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
s+="0";
}
```

I was solving a question and I found "TLE(Time Limit Exceed)" while using first approach but it worked for second one.

Comment: You probably should do `s += std::string( n, '0' );` instead of loop.

Comment: Or even shorter `s.append(n, '0');`

Comment: TLE is usually a symptom of choosing the wrong algorithm when one with a better complexitiy is available. Are you sure that this is the line that costs most?

Comment: @user463035818 yes, I just changed this line and the solution got accepted.

Comment: if thats the case then you hit the one exception where you could really learn something useful from an online judge ;)

Comment: @user463035818 sorry I misunderstood, actually the code below this line is of O(m) where m>n.

Comment: So considering the complexity issue, Your top code is copying an ever-growing string every time it is called, so exhibits n^2 complexity for the character copying, even though the outer loop is O(n). The second form hopefully uses a buffer growth heuristic that means that the buffer grows logarithmicly on each overflow, so although the copies get bigger each time, they also become less frequent, and it is possible to consider that the character copies occur at O(n), but perhaps hard to prove.

Comment: Which helps to demonstrate that complexity is not always obvious.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first one creates an intermediate string (that will be assigned to `s` after the `+` operation), whereas the second one may not (depends on the capacity of the string).

The complexity in worst case is the same in both case, in best case, it's just copying the new string for the second case against a full copy of both strings for the first case (+memory allocation and free).

The fact that your get `TLE` (Time Limit Exceeded) is probably due to this worst case all the time, always copying huge strings instead of just adding something to the existing one (without reallocation). Like vector, there should be some heuristic in `string` to get adequate capacity in advance.

As @Slava said, this example should be written differently, I suppose the actual code is different.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but can you please elaborate it a little more, than it will be more helpful.

Comment: Where do you need some clarification?

Comment: If the type of s is a std::string (and I don't know that for sure) then the first one has to build a temporary string and copy the s contents in to store s+"0" which is then swapped to s and the old string buffer deleted, while the second one can just push_back('0') in the existing buffer, so the second can be faster, except when the string capacity() is exceeded and it has to resize.

Comment: @GemTaylor's explanation probably helped ;)

Answer (score 2):

I know it's an old question. However for any other person may need the answer and since time difference is real sharp in solving problems in contests, I like to remind that

`s = s + "0";`
takes O( len( s ) ) operations. and

`s += "0";`
takes O( 1 ).

or in case you want to append in front and back of a string, it is better to use deque data structure instead of string.